# My ECS task keeps dying as soon as I make a request

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a problem that ECS task keeps dying when I make a request to it.

The task detail says "Essential container in task exited" and 129 exit code.

I realy got no ide what is the resason; there are evne no logs about it.

[image]
[image]

here goes the mess

[image]

task definition I used:

```json
{
  "family": "<family>",
  "requiresCompatibilities": ["FARGATE"],
  "executionRoleArn": "<role>",
  "networkMode": "awsvpc",
  "runtimePlatform": {
    "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX",
    "cpuArchitecture": "ARM64"
  },
  "cpu": "1024",
  "memory": "2GB",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "<name>",
      "image": "<image>",
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "appProtocol": "http",
          "containerPort": 80
        }
      ],
      "cpu": 1024,
      "memory": 2048,
      "essential": true,
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "ecs-prod",
          "awslogs-region": "ap-northeast-2",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "prod"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

ECS service:

```json
{
  "cluster": "<name>",
  "serviceName": "prod-service",
  "taskDefinition": "<def name>",
  "loadBalancers": [
    {
      "targetGroupArn": "<arn>",
      "containerName": "<container name>",
      "containerPort": 80
    }
  ],
  "launchType": "FARGATE",
  "schedulingStrategy": "REPLICA",
  "deploymentController": {
    "type": "CODE_DEPLOY"
  },
  "platformVersion": "LATEST",
  "networkConfiguration": {
    "awsvpcConfiguration": {
      "assignPublicIp": "ENABLED",
      "securityGroups": ["sg"],
      "subnets": ["s1", "s2", "s3"]
    }
  },
  "desiredCount": 1
}
```

I didn't find  health issue on elb either. Of course, server runs perfect on local.

Comment: This is a problem with the software running in your docker container, not ECS/Fargate. You haven't provided any information about that software, so there is no way anyone here can provide any help. You need to increase your logging in that application to log whatever error is occurring when it tries to serve the request. Perhaps it is failing to connect to your database or something, but without much more information all we can do is guess.

Comment: Looks like the health status is unknown. ALB/ELB would not work unless the health status is healthy.